# "Documents and Settings" on h drive goes forever

Tags: windows-8

h drive had windows 7, laptop too slow so i took out the hd. after hooking it up, nothing seemed wrong, till i checked directories. deleted windows, program files, user, etc no prob.. but when you go into "Documents and Settings", the files from c:\user are there.. if you delete a file on g:\Documents and Setting.... it dissapears from c:\user.... Also. in Documents and Setting\all users\application data\ the "application data" you can keep going down and down for example "G:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data"... etc Go deep enough, it shows in properties "G:\DOCUME~1\ALLUSE~1\APPLIC~1\APPLIC~1\APPLIC~1\APPLIC~1\APPLIC~1\APPLIC~1\APPLIC~1\APPLIC~1\APPLIC~1\APPLIC~1\APPLIC~1\APPLIC~1\APPLIC~1\Application Data"

i want to delete the files without deleting the ones in c:\user. also an explanation for the infinity of application data,,,

Answer (score 0):

Symbolic links, otherwise known as symlinks, are basically advanced shortcuts. You can create symbolic links to individual files or folders, and then these will appear like they are stored in the folder with the symbolic link even though the symbolic link only points to their real location.
So your files are actually stored on G:\Documents and Setting... and your symlinks are in c:\user....

G:\DOCUME~1\ALLUSE~1\APPLIC~1\APPLIC~1\APPLIC~1... This is the result of the PC manufacturer incorrectly applying "Junction Point". What you see is not duplication but the effect of folder names referring back to themselves ad infinitum. You could fix the error but since it usually causes no problem you might as well ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

figured it out..
Documents and Settings is not a real folder, but is designated as a system folder for protection.. It a "Junction" folder, and it is there to allow legacy programs tobe used in compatibility mode the Windows 8 folder structure.

You have apparently altered the security permissions, in order to access the folder. In fact, here are no files inside. It points to C:\Users*your user name*\Appdata and C:\Users*your user name*\My Documents. The files you are seeing, and deleting, are virtual here are no files inside. When you delete those files, your are, in reality, deleting the original and real files in the path I have stated. There is no way you can delete one, without the other. Documents and Settings takes up no space and, if you follow the defaults, and keep the System files hidden in the options, you cannot see the folder and it should not be  any sorce of trouble to your.